# How to measure power efficiency increase or decrease for code change

Tags: c++, c, mobile, embedded, profiling

In embedded/mobile environment battery power drain has to be considered when we are developing Software for it, therefore energy efficient software programming matters in embedded/mobile world.

Problem is,(*regarding* ***Assembly/C/C++***)

Think we have stable software release when it's run on arbitrary platform **X** it consumes**Y** amount of power(in Watts), now we are going to carry out some code change and we want to measure how it's gonna effect on energy consumption and its efficiency at build time.

```
INT16U x = OXFFFF;
/... some code in stable release .../
for(;x<4096;++x)
{
   /... some code in stable release .../

   INT64U foo = x >> 256 ? x : 4096 ;  // point 1  sample code change;
   if(~foo & foo) foo %= 64 ;         // point 1  sample code change;

   /... some code in stable release .../
}
```

Simply if we want to measure how this code change `@point1` effects on energy efficiency(*relative to the stable release statistics*) rather than profiling space and time (performance plus memory), If we want to build a simple energy/power analyzing and profiling tool in C/ C++,

- Is there any recommended C/C++ library or source to build power analysis tool?
- If we have to analyze and determine the change in power consumption levels through CPU/GPU instruction level changes for each code change for example as in `point1`, how can we determine power consumption for each instruction for arbitrary CPU or GPU on the respective platform?
- How can developer aware of how much of power consumption reduced or increase due to his code change at Application build time rather than runtime?

Comment: Connect a power-meter on the to the power-supply of the device?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is it accurate enough?

Comment: Yes it is, and basically how everyone checks power-consumption of computers in general.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what is your idea about this ? 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/new-energy-analysis-in-intel-system-studio-2018

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR You can't do it with software, only with a physical meter.

To refine what "@Some programmer dude" already hinted at:

One problem is, that the actual implementation of a certain operation on hardware is unknown. You might get lists with cycles/opcode but you do not know what those cycles do. The can go a long route around, some need more parts to pass some less and so on, hence it is unknown how much power the individual cycle needs.

Another problem are the nearly indeterministic paths in complex code with a large-domain (e.g. 16-bit ADCs) and multiple inputs (e.g.: reading several sensors at once.), especially if you work with floating-point arithmetic.

It is possible to get relative differences in power consumption but only coarse ones. Coarse like in "100 loops of the same code need more power than 10" coarse. Or: if it runs faster it most likely needs less power.

No, you have to swallow the bitter pill and go to the next Rhode&Schwarz (not affiliated, just saw an ad in the sidebar at the moment of writing this) shop and get a power-supply, a meter (two, actually), a frequency generator and the necessary connecting material. Will set you short in the mid to upper five digit range (US $). Once you have it you need to measure the power consumption of several MCUs/CPUs (ca. 30+ to be able to assume uniform distribution) of every single batch of the processor you got.

That is a lot of work and investment if you don't have the tools already. Measuring is also a form of art in itself, you need to know what you are doing, a lot of things can get wrong.

It might be a good idea to spend that money if you want a million dollar contract with the military and need to guarantee your stuff to be able to  run five years on a single battery (and the first thing said military does is slapping a sticker on it that says "Change battery every 6 month!") otherwise: don't even start, not worth the headaches.

Comment: Intel has this tool with their System Studio Package,
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/new-energy-analysis-in-intel-system-studio-2018
Likewise can't we develop something like that? not such advanced but, measure at least how  much energy-hungry is our code

Comment: @Dinithi Intel builds the hardware and compiler and has all the necessary knowledge to measure something (what exactly and how precise is not clear from the webpage you linked) . We on the other side do not have that knowledge and can only stick a meter on it. And there is still the problem of complexity if the input is not known exactly or too big and or too many.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts and ideas, that link has some other info links to their analysis tools.I got it, initially, I thought, by analyzing assembly instructions and gather some reference statistics for our stable code then we could predict how much amount of power gain or dissipate for updated instructions and routines?  (once again assume that we collected pre-sample data for our stable release code since it's the reference we taken in to account)

Comment: @Dinithi and how do you get your reference statistics? Yepp, by measuring. This time a *very* precise measuring. Add a magnitude to the equipment price.

Comment: yeah,It's hard, deamentaemnudi check this out too :D https://www.linkedin.com/learning/windows-power-tools-optimizing-code/collect-data-with-soc-watch

Comment: @Dinithi that is in parts even coarser than the kind of coarse I was talking about. And: he's talking about measuring power consumption, Those tools he talks about do not measure power consumption, they make educated guesses. They have their uses, of course, but not within the large zoo of MCUs. If you wnat to know how long the battery holds in your IoT-device you have to measure it physically.

Comment: got it, deamentiaemundi,Can you mention any text book or blog related these stuff?

Comment: Got this link too - https://jeelabs.org/2012/06/13/code-vs-power-consumption/